# Error about Picker View

Tags: ios

I try to show "man" and "woman" but getting "signal sigabrt". Anyone please help me solve my problem

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pkvTest: UIPickerView!

    var a : [String] = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        a = ["man", "woman"]
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView : UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView : UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component : Int) -> Int {
        return a.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return a[row]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first two picker view functions have the wrong names. The reason for this is that you forgot to declare your view controller as adopting UIPickerViewDataSource. As soon as you do that, the compiler will wake up to the problem and alert you to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Looks like you're missing the delegate and datasource in the viewdidload

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDatasource {

@IBOutlet weak var pkvTest: UIPickerView!

var a : [String] = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

self.pkvTest.delegate = self
self.pkvTest.datasource = self

    a = ["man", "woman"]
}
```

Comment: This can't be the cause of the crash. And the delegate and data source might be hooked up through Interface Builder.